# Using Excel VBA to change HTML attribute with dynamic Classname

Tags: html, vba

I need to add the value in "Seleniumvalue" attribute.

Below HTML tag are before entry

```html
<div class="ng-scope" ng-if="item.type=='string'">
<input class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" onkeypress="checkKeyPressed(event)" type="text" ng-model="item.value" ng-disabled="false" seleniumvalue="" ng-focus="updateOperatorForNullCriteria(item)">
</div>
```

Below HTML tag are after manual entry

```html
<div class="ng-scope" ng-if="item.type=='string'">
    <input class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-not-empty" id="ext-gen1845" onkeypress="checkKeyPressed(event)" type="text" ng-model="item.value" ng-disabled="false" seleniumvalue="Q422-001" ng-focus="updateOperatorForNullCriteria(item)">
 </div>
```

I am trying to update the HTML attribute

Here is the code I am attempting to use:

```
Dim ie As New shdocvw.InternetExplorerMedium

ie.navigate "https://windchill.com/Windchill/app/"

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

ie.Document.querySelector("input[class*=ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched]").setAttribute "seleniumvalue", "Q422-001"
```

[image]

Comment: Is this a VBA question or a VB.NET question? Please make up your mind and delete the irrelevant tag.

Comment: This is not a coding service where you state your requirements and get back ready-to-run debugged code. 
You need to put in some efforts yourself. Show us what you have tried this far.
Also read Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:
**https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**

Comment: And what happens with your code? Note the attribute is `seleniumvalue` btw. Lowercase `s` You also show no page load wait.

Comment: updated the seleniumvalue and check for page in ready state

Comment: And what happens with your code versus what should happen?